# Promise.all not working as expected with array

Tags: angular, typescript, es6-promise

Here is my code, I start with an empty array and want to call a service that does some work with the populated array. I populate the array using two calls to services which call an API to receive elements to insert into the array.

I am trying to use promises to ensure that my array `subscribers` is full of the proper subscriber objects, but the method processSubscribers always receives an empty array even though objects do eventually get added to the subscribers array (as seen in chrome debugging).

```
doSomething(){
    const subscribers: ISubscriber[] = [];
    const promises = [];

    this.selectedChildren.forEach(child => {
        promises.push(this.serviceA.getSubscribers(child.id).subscribe( (subs: ISubscriber[]) => {
            subs.forEach(s => {
                subscribers.push(s);
            });
        }));
    });

    this.selectedSubscribers.forEach(sub => {
        promises.push(this.serviceB.getSubscriber(sub.subscriberId).subscribe( (sub: ISubscriber) => {
            subscribers.push(sub);
        }));
    });

    // subscribers is always empty when this call is made 
    // since above code hasn't finished executing
    Promise.all(promises).then( a => {
        this.serviceC.processSubscribers(this.id, subscribers).subscribe( id => {
            this.toastr.success('Success!');
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of this line of code is a subscription not a promise

```
this.serviceA.getSubscribers(child.id).subscribe( (subs: ISubscriber[]) => {
            subs.forEach(s => {
                subscribers.push(s);
            })
```

It means your `promise` array doesn't include promises and this is why `promise.all` doesn't work

You can do this

`promises.push(this.serviceB.getSubscriber(sub.subscriberId).toPromise())`

or

```
promises.push(this.serviceB.getSubscriber(sub.subscriberId).toPromise().then(x => ... ))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I can't tell you how long I've been stuck on this and all for something so simple. I used your second option and pushed the subscriber objects onto the array in the "then" and it appears to be working now

Comment: @JacobCM glad solved your issue, as a side comment the whole thing is a little smelly, I don't know about the requirement, but I feel there are best practices for it